# Find the number of squares in [0, 8] × [0, 8] ⊆ R^2 whose vertices have integer coefficients and the sides are parallel to the coordinate axes.

Tags: geometry

> Question is in title

Here is an argument

The vertices of a square with sides parallel to the coordinate axes are of the form $(x, y)$, $(x + d, y)$, $(x + d, y + d)$, and $(x, y + d)$, where $x$, $y$, and $d$ are integers. The side length of the square is $d$.

We can count the number of squares with side length d as follows: the lower left corner of the square can be any point in the rectangle $[0, 8 - d] * [0, 8 - d]$, which has $(9 - d) * (9 - d)$ lattice points. Therefore, the number of squares with side length d is $(9 - d) * (9 - d)$.

To count the total number of squares with vertices having integer coefficients, we need to add up the number of squares for each possible side length. The largest possible side length is $8$, which gives $(9 - 8)^2 = 1$ square. The smallest possible side length is $1$, which gives $(9 - 1)^2 = 64$ squares. Therefore, the total number of squares is:

$(9 - 1)^2 + (9 - 2)^2 + ... + (9 - 8)^2
= 8^2 + 7^2 + ... + 1^2
= (8 * 9 * 17)/6
= 204$

Therefore, there are $204$ squares in $[0, 8] * [0, 8]$ with vertices having integer coefficients and sides parallel to the coordinate axes.

Is this in right way...or give another solution

Comment: Why downvoting this question ?

Comment: See here : https://oeis.org/A000330